# iOS Adding Array to Plist Document Root

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object, plist

Okay so after feedback I am doing this changes to my code it's working but just adding and replacing the first one?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *user_id = [prefs objectForKey:@"user_id"];
    NSString *fixture_id = [prefs objectForKey:@"fixture_id"];

    // Get path to documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if ([paths count] > 0)
    {
        NSString  *selectedPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",user_id, fixture_id]];

        // Read both back in new collections
        self.mySelectionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:selectedPath];

        NSLog(@"Players Selected = %@", self.mySelectionsArray);
    }


    NSDictionary *tempDic = [[[self.listOfPlayersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"contacts"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *avatar = [tempDic objectForKey:@"avatar"];
    NSString *avatarSmall = [tempDic objectForKey:@"avatar_small"];
    NSString *first_name = [tempDic objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    NSString *last_name = [tempDic objectForKey:@"last_name"];

    NSDictionary *innerDic;

    innerDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                 [NSArray arrayWithObjects: avatar, avatarSmall, first_name, last_name, nil]
                                            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"avatar", @"avatar_small", @"first_name", @"last_name", nil]];

    self.mySelectionsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:innerDic]];


//    [self.mySelectionsArray insertObject:innerDic atIndex:0];
    [self.mySelectionsArray addObject:innerDic];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([paths count] > 0)
    {
        // Path to save array data
        NSString  *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",user_id, fixture_id]];

        NSLog(@"Path: %@",arrayPath);

        // Write array
        [self.mySelectionsArray writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Which is now checking for array and pulling it down then adding the object

The plist looks like this after selecting a player;

```
{
    "first_name" = Ollie;
    "last_name" = Akroyd;
},
{
    "first_name" = Ollie;
    "last_name" = Akroyd;
}
)
```

Comment: To add object to NSMutableArray use [mySelections addObject:YOUR_OBJ_REF];

Comment: Yeah tried this just replaces the whole object

Comment: Then first get already stored data from plist into `mySelections`, then add new data to `mySelections` array.

Comment: @user3008745 Are you trying to creating a plist containing a number of players that the user has selected or a number of plists each containing a single player?

Comment: I am adding more players to the same plist.

Comment: So I have managed to get it working however now it's crashed because it's trying to look in the wrong key for the blob. Any help  
       (
                {
            ALF =             {
                "first_name" = ALF;
                "last_name" = "";
            };
        }
    ),
        {
        "first_name" = Rob;
        "last_name" = "Afoa Peterson";
    }
)

Line it's crashing on is: 

NSDictionary *cellDict = [[self.usersSelectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ALF"];

Comment: I have editted my question please check :)

Answer (score 1):

Stated your code, mySelections is empty, I guess you want to add innerDic to it; moreover you are saving mySelections instead of userSelections.
You should add innerDic to mySelections and save userSelections to resolve your issue.

**EDIT**
Instead of

```
self.mySelectionsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSDictionary   dictionaryWithDictionary:innerDic]];
```

which overrides the read array, add the object:

```
[self.mySelectionsArray addObject:innerDic];
```

self.mySelectionsArray must be mutable, so instead of

```
self.mySelectionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:selectedPath];
```

write

```
self.mySelectionsArray = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:selectedPath] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Okay I am now doing this:

    innerDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                 [NSArray arrayWithObjects: avatar, avatarSmall, first_name, last_name, nil]
                                            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"avatar", @"avatar_small", @"first_name", @"last_name", nil]];

    self.mySelectionsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:innerDic]];


    [self.mySelectionsArray addObject:innerDic];

But it's just duplicating the array?

Comment: First of all innerDic si a copy of tempDic, which is useless in this case. 
Moreover userSelections is create each time, so it doesn't persist the previous values: I think you need to read the previous save value before adding the updated array.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely something to do with this, any clues? Please check my edited question code.